# How to resolve "Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded error" in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, combinations

I am using this block of code to get all the combinations of the rows of a matrix as I have to apply brute force.

```
function combinations(training)

S=dec2bin(1:2^size(training,1)-1)=='1';
allSubsets=cell(size(S,1),1);
for i=1:size(S,1)
    allSubsets{i}=training(S(i,:),:);
    display(allSubsets{i})

end
end
```

If I run this function on a small matrix of lets say 7 or even 20 rows it works perfectly fine. But once I increase the size of the matrix to 25 it gives me this error.

> Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
>
> Error in dec2bin (line 55)
>   s=char(rem(floor(d*pow2(1-max(n,e):0)),2)+'0');
>
> Error in combination (line 11) S=dec2bin(1:2^size(training,1)-1)=='1';

Moreover, when I increase the number of rows up to 120 it gives me the following error :/

> Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
>   Error in combination (line 11) S=dec2bin(1:2^size(training,1)-1)=='1';

I have to run this on a data of 2000 rows having 69 columns. Please help!!

Comment: You need to rethink how you are generating your subsets for analysis. A `20 x 69` array gives you `723,517,440` elements (5GB of doubles) across the cells of `allSubsets`, which is quite obviously why you're running out of memory.

Comment: Can we resolve this issue by using another way to get the combinations of rows ??

Comment: This bit is the problem: `1:2^size(training,1)`. You said `(training) = 2000×69`, meaning, you're computing 2²⁰⁰⁰ and using that as the number of elements in an array.There are about 4×10⁸⁰ atoms in the universe. Compared to Σ(1:2²⁰⁰⁰), the number of atoms in the universe is like a grain of sand inside all the beaches in existence...in a universe that is filled to the brim with desert planets...and then there's one such universe for each grain of sand on Earth. In other words, there will never exist enough memory to store what you are trying to do, so you'll have to find another way.

Comment: Okay, guys, I have reduced my data from 2000 rows to 500 rows using the least variance filter. Now can we have a code which can give us combinations of these 500 rows without running out of memory :3 : V